# Not able to make synchronous ajax call in Cordova app for windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-8.1

I am using following code to make a synchronous ajax call to load a JS file. Same code is working fine in android, iOs Cordova App and IE 11 on Windows 8.1 but in case of Windows 8.1 Cordova app its not working - here instead of synchronous call it is making an asynchronus call

```
function laodJs(file) {
    var basePath = $.mobile.path.documentBase.directory;
    var URL = "ms-appx://" + basePath + file;
    //var URL =  $.mobile.path.documentBase.directory + file;
    console.log('1: ' + URL);

    //ajax call here

    $.ajax({

        method: 'GET',
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'script',                        

        success: function () {
            console.log('2: Script load success callback');
        },
        error:function () {
            console.log('2: Script load failure callback');
        },
        async: false

    });

    console.log('3: Ouside AJAX call it will excute after Script load success or Script load Failure');
}
```

Comment: Do you get a specific error message or more precision on what is happening ?

Comment: Not getting error message instead of synchronous call its making asynchronous call